# Хочу написать чат на сокетах Python

Tags: python

код клиента

```
import threading
import socket

user = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

user.connect(("localhost", 12))

user.send("123".encode("utf-8"))
data = user.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print (data.encode("utf-8"))
```

код сервера

```
import threading
import socket

# 1. принимать челов
# 2. транслировать их сообщения для других
base = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

base.bind(("", 12))

people = []

def connect_people():
    while 1:
        base.listen()
        conn, adr = base.accept()
        people.append((conn, adr))
        
def get_msg():
    tr = True
    while tr:
        try:
            for pep in range(len(people)):
                msg = people[i][1].recv(1024).decode()
                print(msg)
                if msg:
                    for i in len(len(people)):
                        print(people[i][1])
                        people[i][1].send(msg)
        except Exception as x:
            print(x)
            tr = False
        break
            

t1 = threading.Thread(target = connect_people)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = get_msg)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске обоих ничего не происходит и ошибок тоже нет

Comment: У Вас `break` практически сразу же приводит к выходу из функции `get_msg`.

Comment: А еще ексепшен должен напечатать все что он думает, потому что переменная `i` в строке `msg = people[i][1].recv(1024).decode() ` нигде ранее не встречается. А если бы она все таки была переменной цикла, то возникла бы следующая проблема, recv если данных в соединении нет будет их ждать, если сокет блокирующий (а он таков по умолчанию). А следовательно пока первый клиент не пошлет данные, никакие другие данные от других клиентов получены не будут.

Comment: А после того как вы пофиксите все перечисленные выше ошибки и сделаете сокеты не блокирующими возникнет следующая проблема - 100% загрузка процессора в цикле. Необходимо использовать select, epoll или что то похожее. Или, что явно будет лучше, смотреть в сторону модуля asyncio